# How to get login_name by UserName in AD C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

so i have UserName from Active Directory assigned to variable `"NAME"` and I need to get login_name for this UserName in `System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;`

How i should use `foreach` to get login_name.

Comment: Please add taggs for the programming language and framework. Please explain what you tried so far

Comment: Modified tag.  Add others that are relevant, like @Dirk Horsten mentionned.

Comment: The question is unclear. Please tell us what is stored in the variable `NAME`. Is that DisplayName, FirstName or what?? Also, by `login_name` you mean `sAMAccountName` or `UserPrincipalName` ??